# Python3.7: error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PBKDF2' which is installed with pip3

Tags: python3, pip

I'm running on Ubuntu 19.10. I've installed Python [pbkdf2](https://www.dlitz.net/software/python-pbkdf2/) with

```
pip3 install pbkdf2
```

using `pip3 show` parameter I can see that it is installed.

```
$pip3 show pbkdf2
Name: pbkdf2
Version: 1.3
Summary: PKCS#5 v2.0 PBKDF2 Module
Home-page: http://www.dlitz.net/software/python-pbkdf2/
Author: Dwayne C. Litzenberger
Author-email: dlitz@dlitz.net
License: UNKNOWN
Location: /home/xyz/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages
Requires: 
Required-by:
```

Trying to run this simple code;

```py
import base64
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from pbkdf2 import PBKDF2

salt = 16 * b'\0'
key = PBKDF2(Config.SECRET, salt).read(32)
iv = PBKDF2(Config.SECRET, salt).read(16)
```

Got this error

```
$python3.7 pbkdf2.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pbkdf2.py", line 3, in <module>
    import PBKDF2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PBKDF2'
```

How can I solve this issue?

---

**Note 1:** I've also tried installing `pbkdf2`  with the Ubuntu package manager and that did not solve this issue.

**Note 2:** Using `python3.7 -m pip install pbkdf2`

I've got this

```
 defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
 Requirement already satisfied: pbkdf2 in /home/xyx/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (1.3)
```

If first removed with `pip3 uninstall pbkdf2` then I've got only the first warning.

Comment: we're missing code - `Config.SECRET` is not defined in your program nor imported so it can't be referred to.  Code as is is not even able to begin to be run.  Further, `Crypto.Cipher` is also nonexistent (as it comes from a separate library not shipped with Ubuntu and Python standard libraries) so you have additional packages or classes imported/defined elsewhere that makes it impossible to do testing on this.  This said, I debugged your issue and posted an answer about it - the core problem is User Error, and details on that are in the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The core problem here, [discovered after discussions and additional troubleshooting via a chat room for this question](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105140/discussion-between-thomas-ward-and-kelalaka), was that the file you're trying to run is the exact same name as the library you're trying to import.

Python is very picky in how it checks for libraries.  Generally speaking, Python `import` commands check the following 3 locations for your environment when called directly from a directory in a stock Ubuntu setup.  It also prioritizes these locations as listed:

1. Your current working directory, or the directory being executed from.  (In this case `/home/xyz/Projects/Python/`, which contains `pbkdf2.py` which is the same file you're trying to execute but also carries the exact same name as the thing you're trying to `import` from!)
2. The user's local packages store for Python 3.  This is where `pip3` installed `pbkdf2` from PyPI.
3. The system's packages library (which should only contain Python standard libraries and things you installed with `sudo pip3`).

Because your file is named `pbkdf2.py` and is the same exact name as the library we installed in your user's local packages store for Python 3, it's trying to import from itself, which for obvious reasons fails.  Rename your file `pbkdf2.py` to `pbkdf2_.py` or similar (as long as the name is NOT `pbkdf2.py`) and it should then "just work".

(The reason it then "Just Works" is because because the first case (of checking the Projects directory as the 'sources root' for the project) no longer exists - there is no `pbkdf2.py` file and therefore it can't be imported from.  It then falls back to the second case, your user package-store in `/home/xyz/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages` which is where `pbkdf2` actually lives, so the `import` command is successful.)

Comment: All comments here were [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105140/discussion-between-thomas-ward-and-kelalaka), where additional questions and debugging were done.